# iOS Modularize OpenGL code with Functions Outside of drawView

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a large set of code that utilizes OpenGL.  At this point all OpenGL calls are made from within the

```
-(void)drawView:(UIView *)theView
```

routine.  Within this routine I have large pieces of code that are repeated MANY times, and I am trying to bring those repeated pieces of code out into routine so as to bring down the overall size of the code file, and make more modularized.

In general, I have:

```
double centerX = /*calculated value*/;
double centerY = /*calculated value*/;

/* Some OpenGL code that uses centerX and centerY */
```

When the OpenGL code is within the overridden drawView routine, it works perfectly.  When I attempt to bring it out to lets say

```
-(void)drawSomethingWithCenterX:(double)centerX CenterY:(double)centerY{
    /* same as original code within drawView*/
}
```

it doesn't draw at all.

Im obviously missing something having to do with externally setting the context within the external call, or something.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it had nothing to do with the context, or OpenGL itself being moved, but rather to do with how I was dealing with the vertex arrays.